# A paradigm of finding all irreducible representations for small groups?

Tags: representation-theory, quaternions, characters

**Background (skip if you are not interested):**

I recently began my study of the group representation theory. I encountered this exercise:

> Find all irreducible representations of the quaternion group $Q_8=\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Suppose $n_i$ are the dimensions of all irreducible representations. Then $\sum_i n_i^2=8$. One dimensional representations can be found by brutal force: Since $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C^\times$ is commutative, a representation $(\rho,\mathbb C)$ factors through its abelianization $Q_8/\{\pm1\}$, and hence we check that:

- $\rho(i)=1,\ \rho(j)=1$
- $\rho(i)=1,\ \rho(j)=-1$
- $\rho(i)=-1,\ \rho(j)=1$
- $\rho(i)=-1,\ \rho(j)=-1$

are the only four distinct 1-dimensional representations. Hence $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4=1$ and $n_5\geq2$. Recall that $\sum_i n_i^2=8$ Hence $n_5=2$ and they exhaust all irreducible representations.<s>Finally to find the unique 2-dimensonal irreducible representation, consider</s>

$$\rho:Q_8\to GL_2(\mathbb C)$$
defined by ($I=$ unit matrix)
$$\pm1\mapsto\pm I,\quad i\mapsto\left(\matrix{\sqrt{-1}&\\&1}\right),\quad j\mapsto\left(\matrix{1&\\&\sqrt{-1}}\right),\quad k\mapsto\left(\matrix{\sqrt{-1}&\\&\sqrt{-1}}\right)$$
We check that this indeed a well-defined group homomorphism. It remains to show $(\rho,\mathbb C^2)$ is irreducible. Indeed, if there is a subrepresentation it must be some 1-dimensional $V\subset\mathbb C^2$ invariant under $G$. This means the action of $G$ restricted to $V$ has order $2$, i.e. $-I$ must be trivial on $V$, which is absurd unless $V=0$.

Actually I just realized that the construction above is wrong. Now I want to find a paradigm even more!

**Questions:**

1. While browsing through similar questions I found [this on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109777/reference-for-representations-of-quaternion-group). It says that the 2-dimensional representation can be obtained from the left action of $Q_8$ on the real quaternions (viewed as a 4-dimensional real vector space). I am not sure I understand. How does this method work?
2. Is it a paradigm to consider the action of a group on its group algebra over some field to obtain its irreducible representation? If not, is there some procedure I can follow when I meet a different group?
3. For the quaternion group, its irr. reps. over $\mathbb R$ and over $\mathbb C$ are (almost) identical. Does this mean there is a link between reps. over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$. More specifically, if we have obtained irr. reps. over $\mathbb R$, can we use the infomation to find the ones over $\mathbb C$ or vice versa?
4. I did this exercise because I need it to draw the character table of $Q_8$. One would natually think that there is some infomation lost if the character table is all we have. Does this mean we can somehow find the character table without listing all irreducible representations of a group?

p.s. I am only a beginner. So a method that doesn't require introducing a deeper theory is preferred.

Comment: In your 2d repr, all matrices commute with each other (in particular $ij=ji=k$). I think you need a better repr.

Comment: @Berci I see. I may have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Hint: As elements of $Q_8$ $i$ and $-i$ are conjugate. Therefore the matrices representing them must share the same multiset of eigenvalues. They are simultaneously diagonalizable as one is the power of the other, so w.l.o.g. the eigenvectors are $\binom10$ and $\binom01$. Furthermore, $jij^{-1}=-i$, so action by $j$ must interchange those two eigenspaces.

Comment: With the quaternion algebra $\Bbb{H}$ you can do the following. Multiplication by an element of $Q_8$ gives a left action on $\Bbb{H}$. To make the action $\Bbb{C}$-linear, you need to view $\Bbb{H}$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$ with scalar multiplication from the right, for otherwise the action by $Q_8$ won't commute with scalar multiplication. If you use the $\Bbb{R}$-span of $\{1,i\}$ as your copy of $\Bbb{C}$, then $\{1,j\}$ is a $\Bbb{C}$-basis of $\Bbb{H}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen By "viewing $\mathbb H$ as a vector space over $\mathbb C$" do you mean tensoring it with $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your first comment. That helps. And I think your second comment is what I am asking about in question 1. Can you elaboate in an answer? Because some techniques are still pretty strange to me.

Comment: No, Jyrki does not mean the tensor product $\Bbb H\otimes_{\Bbb R}\Bbb C$ (which would be a 4D complex vector space). The point of tensoring a real vector space with $\Bbb C$ is to make it possible to multiply by complex scalars, but we can already multiply $\Bbb H$ by complex scalars (on the right) so there's no need to tensor! Every quaternion is uniquely expressible as $\alpha+j\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb C$, so $\Bbb H$ is a 2D complex (right) vector space with basis $\{1,j\}$.

Comment: General procedures for finding character tables and all representations may be a bit broad. But it's worth pointing out, the character table can be used to reconstruct all the irreps (irreducible representations), and all the irreps appear as subreps of the group algebra (aka regular representation). Also, one can turn real reps into complex reps with "induction" and turn complex reps into real reps with "restriction." (The same works for any field extension.)